# Is it possible to create your own WinDriver class for windows standalone application via implementing selenium WebDriver interface?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please tell me the process if its possible to create a driver for windows application using selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

No two windows applications use the same tools to build their UI, nor will they use the same language for their UI, so I would say no, it is not possible to build a driver for "windows applications". It *might* be possible for one *specific* application, but most likely not, as UI hooks are generally not exposed anywhere outside the application source code, so selenium would have no way to find the elements.

Comment: It *might* be possible, but unless I know which application I cannot determine this. It is **highly unlikely** to be possible though.